# Apigility basics: ServiceNotCreatedException

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm following [this tutorial](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/12/03/create-a-restful-api-with-apigility/) and [this one](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service) to create a basic REST API with Apigility, I'm no expert in Zend as my goal is to build the api over a symfony2 app, but for now, after following all steps in both tutorials, I reach the same point, when accessing `http://api.example.com/endpoint1` I get an Exception:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException

File:

/var/www/api.example.com/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1070

Message:

An abstract factory could not create an instance of exampleapiv1restprovinciacontroller(alias: ExampleAPI\V1\Rest\Provincia\Controller).
```

Comment: There should be a controller and a factory class in ExampleAPI\V1\Rest\Provincia\Controller\. Please  post them.

Comment: What if I have only 4 files in this directory? Collection, Entity, Resource and ResourceFactory? There's no any controllers.

Answer (score 0):

See if the user  that run webserver has [permission to write](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/getting-started#note-file-system-permissions) in the project folder.

See if you have [disabled opcache and others code chaches](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/installation#note-about-opcache) (like APC).

The Apigility need permissions to generate and change files on the `/config` and `/modules` folders.